# Firebase Auth with several users in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to use Firebase Auth with several users in Flutter.
I mean I want to log in with the user1 and log in with the user2 Simultaneously to the system without logout from user 1.

How can I do that ؟
how can I change between user one and user two?
Is there a way to save credentials of use and restore them to implement several users in Flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Authentication SDKs only allow a single client to be signed in at any time.

So that means that in order to have multiple users signed in to your app, you will need to spawn multiple instances of the Firebase Authentication SDK. If you look at the [example from pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/example), you will need to initialize a `FirebaseApp` and a `FirebaseAuth` instance for each user you want to sign in - and then manage those instances yourself.